# Python import a module from another file by mentioing the same directory

Tags: python, module

The below is my directory structure
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slbTi.png)

and my code in test.py which imports LOC from the conf.py under main/configs folder

```
import bcrypt 
from main.configs.conf import LOC

password = 'password123'

bytes = password.encode('utf-8') 
salt = bcrypt.gensalt() 
hash = bcrypt.hashpw(bytes, salt) 

print(hash)
```

contents of conf.py

```
LOC = {"australia": "au"}
```

test.py is located under main folder. if we run the test.py we get No module named main error.

if we change the import line to configs.conf from main.configs.conf the code works. what can we do to make sure it works starting with main? The reason is our existing code has from main. imports in all the files and it works fine in prod and dev. What can we do to make this work locally? This is to make sure that we have the same code running local;ly and can run without issues. I tried adding **init**.py in the directories as well.

I tried putting **init**.py under the main and configs directory

expected the error will go

Comment: `sys.path.append("..")` might be a quick and dirty option. Of course that is relative to your cwd.

Comment: is this to be run anywhere? Note that the same code is working in our deployed environment.

Comment: In your deployed env, you are not running files out of the main folder but the folder above it.

Answer (score 1):

**You could add your project root to Python Path:**

In your **test.py** file, add the following lines at the beginning to ensure that the root of your project is in the Python path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/project')
```

Comment: In the existing code of test.py there is no lines like this and it works. Is there anything that I can add in the environment?

Comment: are you sure that the project structure is the same?